# Is there such a map $c:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for an example of a map $c:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ which satisfies the following

for all $k,l,m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have

$$c(k,l)\cdot c(k+l,m)=c(k,m)\cdot c(l,k+m)$$

Here's what I can figure out easily:

Without loss of generality $c(0,0)=1$ otherwise divide everything by $c(0,0)$.

for $k=0$ we get $c(0,l)\cdot c(l,m) = c(0,m)\cdot c(l,m)$ and so $c(0,\cdot)=c(0,0)=c(\cdot,0)=1$.

Finally if we take $m=0$ and use the above we get $c(k,l)=c(l,k)$.

It will be nice if one could completely characterize all such maps. But I'm only looking for an example.

Comment: What if $c(0, 0) = 0$?

Comment: @enedil I edited the title too. The map takes values in $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial example is $c(x,y)=t^{xy}$, here $t$ is a nonzero real number. But I don't know how to completely characterize all such maps.